# Python Win32GUI Find Window

Tags: python, winapi, findwindow

I have a GUI Windows application and I want to control it using the extension Win32gui in Python. How can I find the string `s` that I must give to the FindWindow function?

I need to use the following code:

```
import win32gui as gui
gui.FindWindow(s, None)
```

Thaks!

Comment: Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/

Comment: @leoluk: Thanks +1, but I really need to use win32gui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would usually use a tool like Spy++ (comes with Visual Studio) or some of the alternatives: [Windows Spy](http://www.windows-spy.com), [WinCheat](http://alinconstantin.dtdns.net/Download/WinCheat/Default.htm) or [Window Detective](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowdetective/)